# Naive Bayesian for Topic detection using "Bag of Words" approach

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, naivebayes

I am trying to implement a naive bayseian approach to find the topic of a given document or stream of words. Is there are Naive Bayesian approach that i might be able to look up for this ?

Also, i am trying to improve my dictionary as i go along. Initially, i have a bunch of words that map to a topics (hard-coded). Depending on the occurrence of the words other than the ones that are already mapped. And depending on the occurrences of these words i want to add them to the mappings, hence improving and learning about new words that map to topic. And also changing the probabilities of words.

How should i go about doing this ? Is my approach the right one ?

Which programming language would be best suited for the implementation ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Existing Implementations of Naive Bayes**

You would probably be better off just using one of the existing packages that supports document classification using naive Bayes, e.g.:

**Python** - To do this using the Python based **[Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK)](http://www.nltk.org/)**, see the [**Document Classification**](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html#document-classification) section in the freely available [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book).

**Ruby** - If Ruby is more of your thing, you can use the **[Classifier](http://classifier.rubyforge.org/)** gem. Here's sample code that detects  [whether Family Guy quotes are funny or not-funny](http://www.igvita.com/2007/05/23/bayes-classification-in-ruby/).

**Perl** - Perl has the [**Algorithm::NaiveBayes**](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-NaiveBayes/lib/Algorithm/NaiveBayes.pm) module, complete with a sample usage snippet in the package [synopsis](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-NaiveBayes/lib/Algorithm/NaiveBayes.pm#SYNOPSIS).

**C#** - C# programmers can use **[nBayes](http://nbayes.codeplex.com/)**. The project's home page has sample code for a simple spam/not-spam classifier.

**Java** - Java folks have **[Classifier4J](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/)**. You can see a training and scoring code snippet [here](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html#Using_BayesianClassifier).

**Bootstrapping Classification from Keywords**

It sounds like you want to start with a set of keywords that are **known to cue for certain topics** and then use those keywords to [**bootstrap a classifier**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28machine_learning%29).

This is a reasonably clever idea. Take a look at the paper [**Text Classication by Bootstrapping with Keywords, EM and Shrinkage**](http://www.kamalnigam.com/papers/keywordcat-aclws99.pdf) by McCallum and Nigam (1999). By following this approach, they were able to improve classification accuracy from the 45% they got by using hard-coded keywords alone to 66% using a bootstrapped Naive Bayes classifier. For their data, the latter is close to human levels of agreement, as people agreed with each other about document labels 72% of the time.

Comment: The C# developers also can use [Accord Framework.NET](http://accord-framework.net/). Naive Bayes documentation [here](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/N_Accord_MachineLearning_Bayes.htm)