# Java text classification problem

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, text-processing, classification

I have a set of Books objects, classs **Book** is defined as following :

```
Class Book{

String title;
ArrayList<tags> taglist;

}
```

Where **title** is the title of the book, example : *Javascript for dummies*.

and **taglist** is a list of tags for our example : *Javascript, jquery, "web dev", ..*

As I said a have a set of books talking about different things : IT, BIOLOGY, HISTORY, ...
Each book has a title and a set of tags describing it..

I have to classify automaticaly those books into separated sets by topic, example :

IT BOOKS :

- Java for dummies
- Javascript for dummies
- Learn flash in 30 days
- C++ programming

HISTORY BOOKS :

- World wars
- America in 1960
- Martin luther king's life

BIOLOGY BOOKS :

- ....

Do you guys know a classification algorithm/method to apply for that kind of problems ?

A solution is to use an external API to define the category of the text, but the problem here is that books are in different languages : french, spanish, english ..

Comment: Yes, but there are some common tags between the books :(

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781752/naive-bayesian-for-topic-detection-using-bag-of-words-approach/2783356#2783356

Comment: Sigh..the answers for this question seem to be all over the place with some of them **mistakenly (?)** treating it as a simple homework question on basic data structures. Yox, could you confirm that this is a **text-classification** task where you want to take books tagged with keywords and then use some sort of **classification** algorithm to map the books to the appropriate topics?

Comment: have you been already given the category for each book (i dont mean tags) ?

Comment: @dmcer : this is exactly what i want to do, data is stored in a relational DB i'm creating Book objects from it.

@adi92 : No, i don't have the catogory title, i have to guess/generate it automaticaly

Comment: @yox: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Youssef, have you had a chance to try one of the suggested approaches/tools for text categorization? If so, how did it work out for you?

Comment: DMelt has a number of text classification examples. Look at the DMelt project http://jwork.org/dmelt under section examples, and look at the text classification.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This looks like a reasonably straightforward keyword-based classification task. Since you're using Java, good packages to consider for this would be [**Classifier4J**](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/), [**Weka**](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), or [**Lucene Mahout**](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/).

**Classifier4J**

Classifier4J supports classification using [**naive Bayes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) and a [**vector space**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) model.

As seen in this [**source code snippet**](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html#Using_BayesianClassifier) on training and scoring using its naive Bayes classifier, the package is reasonably easy to use. It's also distributed under the liberal [Apache Software License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License).

**Weka**

Weka is a very popular tool for data mining. An advantage of using it is that you'd be able to readily experiment with using numerous [different machine learning models](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~ablumer/weka/README.html#Classifiers) to categorize the books into topics including [**naive Bayes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), [**decision trees**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree), [**support vector machines**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), [**k-nearest neighbor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm), [**logistic regression**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), and even a [**rule set based learner**](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/weka-3-2/weka.classifiers.j48.PART.html).

You'll find a tutorial on using Weka for text categorization [**here**](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA).

Weka is, however, distributed under the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html). You won't be able to use it for closed source software that you want to distribute. But, you could still use it to back a web service.

**Lucene Mahout**

Mahout is designed for doing machine learning on very large datasets. It's built on top of [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) and supports supervised classification using naive Bayes.

You'll find a tutorial covering how to use Mahout for text classification [**here**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mahout/index.html?ca=drs-#N10401).

Like Classifier4J, Mahout is distributed under the liberal [Apache Software License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License).

Comment: used classfier4j ,  VectorClassifier worked the best for me

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking to make a Map of Tags that holds a Collection of Books?

EDIT:

Sounds like you might want to take a look at a [Vector Space Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) to apply classification of categories.

Either [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Classifier4j](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/) offer a framework for this.

Comment: I'm looking to make a map of books objects where the key is the category name.

Comment: @yox: Make that map. That's your answer.

Comment: I don't want books by tag .. I want books by topic (the map key) which is not present here, it will be an artificialy generated string

Comment: @yox: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Do you not want something as simple as this?

```
Map<Tag, ArrayList<Book>> m = {};
for (Book b : books) {
    for (tag t : b.taglist) {
        m.get(t).add(b);
    }
}
```

Now `m.get("IT")` will return all IT books, etc...

Sure some books will appear in multiple categories, but that happens in real life, too...

Comment: No, tags is if you want a list of significant words in the book..
it will help for grouping books.

Comment: @yox: ah so you want to classify the topic based on the set of tags the book has? or based on the book text? and the tags / book text can be in different languages?

Comment: exaclty, i want to classify using only tags and the tags are in different languages.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look up [fuzzy matching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) such as Soundex and Levenshtein.

Comment: Cool, this is a great way to calculate distance between 2 strings, thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you would use Soundex and Levenshtein to map lists of keywords to topics?