# Text classification categorisation pointers

Tags: text, machine-learning, data-mining, classification, categorization

i am trying to develop a very simple program for classifying and categorising documents using various algorithms. My problem, since i am a beginner is that i cannot find good articles or websites for simple tutorials of how to get started with it. I have read quite few resources and i have learnt a lot of things but each document,site etc i read it uses different techniques, it analyses the problem in different way, proposing different solutions etc. so i am getting confused. Is there any good resources that you can point me to in order to get started with actual implementation?

Also i am looking for actual test data and specifically documents that are categorised so i can "feed" my algorithms. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are programming in Java then this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821575/java-text-classification-problem) might be of good help for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python, check out the [scikit-learn tutorial on text classification](http://scikit-learn.github.com/scikit-learn-tutorial/working_with_text_data.html). See also its [demo script](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#example-document-classification-20newsgroups-py) that runs dozens of different text classification algorithms (including Naive Bayes and SVMs) on the [twenty newsgroups](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/20Newsgroups/) benchmark data set. [Disclaimer: I co-wrote these things.]

For Weka, here's a [tutorial](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA).

Comment: thanks i am currently looking the dataset and it is pretty useful but since i program in Java the python examples seems so confusing. Also for WEKA i tried it before but it does not actually have proper documentation. The tutorial for WEKA is a but limited not saying much. Do you know any other Java methods or pointers to it? Thanks for you response.